# android Read Phone State

Tags: android, email

I need help with app(or service?) basically I was just fooling around, and decided to see if I can make my app send an email if it detects my phone is ringing. (I know it seems stupid but its more of a proof of concept for me. I made custom class in my app (no default main activity) I don't think its getting executed.. I set a toast message to pop up when the app is running, but I never saw one show up. So, I figured I need to do something to make my class execute as if its the default one, and if so, how would I go about doing that? In the android manifest, the only things I added to that were the permissions of read_phone_state, and internet(in case it was needed to send an email)

My question is what would I need to change (no need to debug it.) to make it work? Do I need to add extra info in my manifest file? Do I need to change settings where it will execute "callservice" class when the app first starts? Please, and thanks.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    PhoneStateListener listener;
    TelephonyManager tm;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service has started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        listener = new MyphoneStateListener();
        tm = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        tm.listen(listener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);



    }

    public class MyphoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener
    {
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber)
        {
             switch (state) {  
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:   
                    break;  
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING: 
                   sendemail(); 
                    break;  
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:  
                default:  
                    break;  
                }  
                super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);  
            }
        }

        private void sendemail()
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            i.setType("message/rfc822");
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL , new String[]{"random@gmail.com"});
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT , "phone is ringing");
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT , "email successfully sent");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "send mail..."));
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Email has been sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                try
                {
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send Email..."));
                }
                catch(android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex)
                {

                }
        }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: I doubt your Service is starting in the first place, Services don't just autostart. First, make a MainActivity and make that start your Service.

Answer (score 0):

as in doc [onCallStateChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html#onCallStateChanged%28int,%20java.lang.String%29) take two parameters first `int state` and second is  `String incomingNumber` but in your current code you are just passing single parameter to it means your are not overriding onCallStateChanged method of [PhoneStateListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html) change your code as to work :

```
class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener{  

        @Override  
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {  
            switch (state) {  
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:   
                break;  
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING: 
               sendemail(); 
                break;  
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:  
            default:  
                break;  
            }  
            super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);  
        }  

    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was wondering how would I put this in a thread or asynctask? Seems my program crashes, and I tried to put it in a thread, and it still is not working. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @user1884552 : well post your new code and log also then i will try to help u

Comment: Ok, I added the new code. I read up on it, but I still have trouble understanding it.

Comment: @user1884552 : make sure you have added Internet or Read phone state permission in manifest xml

Comment: @user1884552 : your code looking good can u tell me when it's crashing?

Comment: Well, I called the class, and methods in my activity like so, Callservice callservice = new Callservice(); then I would use the class name and method (which could be whats crashing it) callservice.onCreate(); here idk what method I need to call for it to work correctly. Oh also it crashes right when it loads up, which I am assuming it needs a thread or a synctask for it to stop with the crashing.

Comment: @user1884552 : this is wrong way to call any service method in other class but i'm not able to see this code in your current code as posted by u

Comment: I re edit my code in the main post, or OP if people prefer it that way.

Comment: @user1884552 : i' still not able to find  Callservice callservice = new Callservice();  line in your current code if you have then remove it

Comment: I am sorry that was in my mainactivity.

Comment: @user1884552 : not an issue friend but problem is you have asked here different question for which my answer is current when you post it. so this is also not valid way to solve issue here .if you have any new other issue then always post it as new question .then you will get better and quick answers